# Unable to access values in Request

Tags: python, django

I am not understanding how to access values in my POST request from within my Python API.

**Why can I not access the values in my API Request?** I am clearly getting them in the request.body, but am unable to retrieve them.

I have tried the following methods:

```
request.POST['username']
request.POST.get('username')
```

I receive an error stating **django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError:**

Here is the request.body, which does not seem like JSON at all.

```
"{\n \"username\": \"TestUsername\",\n \"password\": \"TestPass\"\n}"
```

**POST REQUEST**

```
{
  "username": "TestUsername",
  "password": "TestPass"
}
```

**HEADERS**

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

**VIEW**

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
    user = User()
    if 'username' in request.POST and 'password' in request.POST:
        user.username = request.POST['username']
        user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
        user.save()
        return Response({'Status' : 'Complete'})
    else:
        return Response({'Status': 'Incomplete'})
```

Comment: Could you include the stack trace of the MultiValueKeyDict error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that because your `Content-Type` header is `application/json`, you first need to parse the request body as JSON:

```
import json

body = json.loads(request.POST)
```

Although I would think that Django should automatically handle this. Let me know if it works out for you!

EDIT: Looks like you're using Django REST Framework. If so: access your data using `request.data` instead of `request.POST['key']`.

Comment: You are awesome. I didn't realize that I was using a special version of request. I assumed it was just a standard request object as I didn't import any specific case. I am still very new to Python.